# How to filter JSONField by key value in Django to retrieve similar values using MySQL/MariaDB database

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-rest-framework, mariadb

I am trying to retrieve similar values to a specific key value from a JSONField using a mariadb:10.3.28 database. I have used 3 different options as listed for `views.py` all of which do not work.

According to Django documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#containment-and-key-lookups) this can be done with an exact match to the key value, yet I would like to filter with the value only being similar and not exact.

There is an example for using `KeyTextTransform` or `KeyTransform` (https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27205) but this is used with PostgreSQL only.

Is there another way of doing this with a MySQL or MariaDB database?

A post request is made to the following end-point with parameter name `description` as follows:

```
http://localhost/get_meta/?description=text
```

Data Example:

```
{
  "meta": {
      "description": "The description text.",
      "field": 1
  }
}
```

models.py

```
class Model(models.Model):
    meta = models.JSONField(default=dict)
```

views.py

Option 1:

```
def get_meta(self, request):
    queryset = Model.objects.filter(meta__contains=request.GET.get('description') or "")
    serializer_class = ModelSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    data = {'data': serializer_class.data}
    return Response(data)
```

Option 2:

```
def get_meta(self, request):
        queryset = Model.objects.filter(meta__description__contains=request.GET.get('description') or "")
        serializer_class = ModelSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        data = {'data': serializer_class.data}
        return Response(data)
```

Option 3:

```
def get_meta(self, request):
        queryset = Model.objects.filter(meta__contains={'description':request.GET.get('description') or ""})
        serializer_class = ModelSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        data = {'data': serializer_class.data}
        return Response(data)
```

Comment: Please be specific about whether you're using MySQL or MariaDB, and also what version. MariaDB is not MySQL, in particular their JSON implementations are different.

Comment: Updated with MariaDB version, I think there is a way to do this with PostgreSQL according to Django documentation since the ORM supports this. But I want to know if it can be done using MariaDB or MySQL.